# Why isn't there a "SHARE YOUR OWN CODE" community or a "TOP IDEAS" community?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I sometimes tried to add the solution to a problem on Stack Overflow, so once I made code myself that I tried to share with the option "Answer your own question". It was CSS code, and PowerShell code. And I suddenly received negative votes. I'm not even told what I did wrong. Why was I given that negative vote, if the code worked very well? Maybe someone needs it. And it took me a few days to do this code.

Of course, I deleted those posts.

But such a thing is impossible. Making a code, giving a share, is a possibility to somehow contribute to this world of the Internet. I don't want to collect points, I don't care what ranking I have, etc. I don't have a website, I don't have time to make a website if I found four solutions to some problems related to code in Python or Java, for example.

And I don't think it's fair to receive negative votes if I tried to add a code that works very well, just because there is someone who doesn't like it.

I noticed that there aren't any ethics here on Stack Overflow. Sometimes someone tries to solve a problem in Python, yes, but he doesn't know Python, because he is an electronics professional. And he is a very good electronics professional, but he can't know computer science either. So again he gets a lot of negative votes.

Therefore, the idea of ​​giving a code-based aid should also be encouraged. Not everyone wants to collect points on Stack Overflow; most are looking for solutions to problems. Don't forget that! It's about the Internet. Part of the way the Internet works, you learn to connect with other minds. Everyone has to help each other. It's called evolution.

Maybe one has a very good idea, but someone else knows how to put it into practice. Maybe one managed to solve a problem, and knowing how hard it was for him/her to find the solution, he/she wants to share it.

You need to review how to build Stack Overflow. And, most importantly, stop giving negative points. Try to move the post to the right section, so as not to discourage beginners.

So, I think there should be created two more communities on the Stack Overflow: "Share Your Own Code" and "Top Ideas".

In order to develop the Internet and web technology, you must offer as many possibilities as possible to all users, not just advanced ones. And don't forget that there are two kinds of people: those who have very good ideas, and those who know how to solve problems. One is the designer, the other is the builder. Often, one can't succeed without the other.

Comment: Posting self-answered questions is actually encouraged, but they have to follow the usual guidelines of the question/answer format. It your contribution was downvoted, it might not have honored those guidelines. Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Apart from that - "_And I don't think it's fair to receive negative votes if I tried to add a code that works very well, just because there is someone who doesn't like it._" - self answered posts on Stack Exchange sites are treated the same way as any other post, which includes being open to votes and other moderation methods for quality control. If you reject that idea and want to post your solution without all that, a personal blog would probably be a better solution.

Comment: @Tufkamt a personal blog would probably be a better solution for that. Not everyone has time to build a blog, just for one solution. In addition, google will not index or rate a blog with a single post.

Comment: To make this post more constructive: could you please post a link so we have an actual example? Perhaps there's something wrong with your post that is easy to fix.

Answer (score 13):

There isn't a "share your own code" or "top ideas" community because that aren't topics that fit well in a question and answer model. For proper questions to get a proper answer you need enough knowledgeable users that are prepared to stick around and provide answers and you need to build up a collection of knowledge that is valuable for generations to come.

Looking at "your code" or reading about "your idea" is at best entertaining, with answers that are useful to you, but unlikely to help many others.

There are (were) other sites on the Internet that *offer as many possibilities as possible to all users*. Those are called forums ([Yahoo! Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers)) and serve your needs perfectly. In the Stack Exchange Network the strategy is explicitly to not copy that and have a very strictly defined and moderated topicality. And that model can only survive if we do what all these other sites don't: vote, close and delete content that is not on par with the site scope. So the criteria for the code you posted isn't: *does it work*, but *does it add unique value to the existing knowledge base*. Not everything goes here.

As for your argument that you don't have time to create a website or maintain a blog and instead prefer to litter our site: Think about the roughly 22,000 people that you reached already. Those 22,000 spend time reading your posts. If we want them to continue doing that they better find something that was useful to them. If they conclude all they found was useful at best to you, they might not return, ever. Without visitors, no site. I'm not ready to give that up.

You say *One is the designer, the other is the builder* and that might be true.  We carefully split those over several sites. Looking at software you'll find the *designer* at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and the *builder* at Stack Overflow or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

**TL;DR** 
None of those communities would be a good fit for the Q/A model and you won't find enough users that are prepared to provide content, let alone moderate it. Create a [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/) to share your code and ideas.